# What does the F suffix indicate in Intel Xeon/server CPU model numbers?

Tags: cpu

Some Intel server processors have an F suffix in their model numbers. What does the F suffix indicate? I've noticed this mostly in Xeon and Phi processors.

Example: Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8176F Processor

Comment: Your question title should specify "Xeon" or "server" processors, because the F suffix on desktop such as i9-9900KF means "Requires discrete graphics" aka "No integrated graphics" - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to the Omni-Path Architecture. Check the notes section in the [cpu-world specs page for 8176F](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%208176F.html), and you'll notice Omni-Path mentioned. 
Details about the chip can be found [here](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cores/skylake_sp), which mention Omni-Path.

> Additionally, models that are suffixed with "F" (SKL-F) integrate the Omni-Path Host Fabric Interface (HFI) die on-package.

Comment: This answer is correct.  [This](http://ark.intel.com/products/125056/Intel-Xeon-Platinum-8176F-Processor-38_5M-Cache-2_10-GHz) vs [This](https://ark.intel.com/products/120508/Intel-Xeon-Platinum-8176-Processor-38_5M-Cache-2_10-GHz) makes it clear

Comment: Well CPU World made the statement but the specifications match the statement details.  So I assume their statement about the model name is correct

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the AVX-512 Foundation extension.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512

Comment: This doesn't make sense considering AVX-512 is widely supported across Intel products including those that don't have a F in their model name.  Link-only answer are typically frowned upon.

Comment: "AVX-512 Foundation" This just indicates the group of instructions which are 32-bit/64-bit that support 512 bit registers